# Create layout code that can be shared between many activities

Tags: android, android-layout, popover, code-reuse

[image: 1]

This is a screenshot of a popup which is used for confirmation. I use this type of popup window in many ways, so created the close button `X`. I include the close button xml in the layout for all my popups, but I want it to be re-used (shared).

I don't know how to create the button programatically in android so I can save to a common file and use with all activities. For example, I could create closeButton.java and then include the close button on any-layout with a common click listener on it.

Answer (score 1):

Android `Views`, even those referred to in the xml files, are simply Java classes. You can create a `CloseButton.java` class which `extends Button`, put the logic in there and then just use this class in all your xml layouts, like any other `View`:

```
<com.example.project.by.nicky.CloseButton
    android:id="@+id/someId"
    android:layout_width=""
    android:layout_height="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is creating a costume view that extend android button or image, this will be your X button.

Than from the constructor of your view, just register for click event.

```
class XButton extends ImageView{

    public XButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public XButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public XButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do some thing
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    // use MyPopUpWindow as below no need to create layout in each activity
    MyPopUpWindow popup = new MyPopUpWindow(this);
    popup.setContentView(your_layout);
    popup.setConfirmationListener(new ConfirmationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onConfirm() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

}
```

MyPopUpWindow Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class MyPopUpWindow extends PopupWindow {


private Button mCrossBtn;
private Button mConfirmationBtn;
private ConfirmationListener mConfirmationListener;

public MyPopUpWindow(Context ctx){
    super(ctx);
}
@Override
public void setContentView(View contentView) {
    super.setContentView(contentView);

    mCrossBtn = contentView.findViewById(R.id.cross_button_id);
    mCrossBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            MyPopUpWindow.this.dismiss();
        }
    });

    mConfirmationBtn = contentView.findViewById(R.id.confirm_button_id);
    mConfirmationBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(mConfirmationListener != null){
                mConfirmationListener.onConfirm();
            }
        }
    });
}


interface ConfirmationListener{
    public void onConfirm();
}

public void setConfirmationListener(ConfirmationListener l) {
    mConfirmationListener = l;
}
}
```